# Использование VueJs не для SPA

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-9

Доброе время суток, имеем Laravel 9, TailwindCss

И остро встал вопрос создания модальных окон, бокового offcanvas меню и тд.

Хотелось для этих целей использовать компоненты Vue js.
Вопрос собственно в том можно ли так использовать вью? Т.есть каркас собран на Blade шаблонах со стандартным роутингом и только некоторые элементы на vue? (Проект не SPA)

Comment: Можно, почему же нельзя?

Comment: Вот пример: [Комбинированный подход с Vue и Blade в Laravel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCAX6Dp7hpQ)